# using Underscore and Immutable together

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, immutable.js

I am attempting to integrate Immutable.js into a project that uses Underscore.js. Seemingly Underscore methods are being overwritten by Immutable. Items like _.map and _.toArray are now failing with errors. I assumed that module namespacing would mitigate this problem. I am working in modules based on requireJS. Is there some way to separate these namespaces? Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is the error you getting?

Comment: they all surround parameter types. Objects missing properties that used to be there but now are not. I get values back in the construct for instance like the singular item passed back in the map that makes no sense. The overriding difference being, that in underscore the first parameter is the collection and the first parameter in Immutable is the function, much like when you use map directly off an array. thanks for any help with this

Comment: function 'getValue' was not found in object s. That is the error I am getting

Comment: I found out that an older version of underscore.string was causing the problem. It needed to be exported differently